# Can Selenium+IE hide the browser window?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The system under test only support IE browser. Can Selenium+IE hide the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide window with hotkeys ALT-SPACE-N with **Java** Robot

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
Thread.sleep(50);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
```

Also one of possible solutions - AutoIt

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual framebuffer like [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) or virtual desktops. All known to me linux distributions and windows 10 support virtual desktop feature "out of the box", and windows 7-8 might need software like Dexpot or something similar.